# Custom variable name in fileglob instead of item

Tags: ansible

Here is usage of fileglob:

```
- name: Copy each file over that matches the given pattern
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "/etc/fooapp/"
    owner: "root"
    mode: 0600
  with_fileglob:
    - "/playbooks/files/fooapp/*"
```

but is there an option to use custom variable name instead of {{ item }} ?

when using "normal" loop there is:

```
  loop_control:
    loop_var: item_name
```

is there something like this possible while using fileglob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's possible. Instead of *with_fileglob* use *loop* [*query*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#invoking-lookup-plugins-with-query) or [*lookup*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_lookups.html#lookups). For example

```
  loop: "{{ query('fileglob', '/playbooks/files/fooapp/*') }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: item_name
```